# How turn off delimiter while writing to a file using Spring Batch ItemWriter

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am trying to generate a flat file in the following format which does not have any delimiter.

Customer.java

```
 private String customerId;
 private String customerName;
```

MyFlatFileItemWriter.java

```
@Component
public class MyFlatFileItemWriter {


    @Bean(name = "myWriter")
    public FlatFileItemWriter<Customer> bondEdgeFlatFileItemWriter() {
        return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Customer>()
                .name("myWriter")
                .resource(new FileSystemResource("myFileNameWithPath"))
                .delimited().delimiter("")
                .names(new String[] {"customerId", "customerName" })
                .build();
    }
}
```

I am expecting below in output file `myFileNameWithPath.txt`.

```
123Jorge Martin
911Donald Trump
```

here as you see there is no delimiter either comma(,) or pipe(|) expected in the file. But I am getting default delimiter "," in the output file even if I don't set anything or set empty as the delimiter. Please let me know how to write the field values as is without any delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that the empty String as delimiter [is ignored](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/file/builder/FlatFileItemWriterBuilder.java#L462) and you end up having the default delimiter which is ','. I think this is a bug in Spring Batch because this does not happen when you set an empty delimiter in the writer directly without using the builder. Please open an issue with a reference to this SO question and we will fix it.

> Please let me know how to write the field values as is without any delimiter.

In the meantime, you can use the following which should work:

```
@Bean(name = "myWriter")
public FlatFileItemWriter<Customer> bondEdgeFlatFileItemWriter() {
    BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Customer> fieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
    fieldExtractor.setNames(new String[] {"customerId", "customerName" });
    DelimitedLineAggregator<Customer> lineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();
    lineAggregator.setDelimiter("");
    lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(fieldExtractor);

    return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Customer>()
            .name("myWriter")
            .resource(new FileSystemResource("customers.txt"))
            .lineAggregator(lineAggregator)
            .build();
}
```

Comment: with space as a delimiter, it is generating the file with space(" ") as a delimiter.

Comment: the space that you see is not the space between two fields, rather it is space in customerName field. I don't want any delimiter between fields.

Comment: I misunderstood the question, sorry for that. I updated the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, Mahmoud. Can you please share me the link to open the issue, please.

Comment: Here is the link to the Jira of the project: https://jira.spring.io/projects/BATCH.